# Why does dynamically created element with Dragstart event returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

The following code creates new elements and ascribes an dragstart event to it. However it results in an "undefined".
What am I doing wrong?

```
    for (var S = 0; S < arrInbound[i][3].length; S++){      
        var namesDiv = document.createElement('div');
        namesDiv.id = S;
        namesDiv.draggable = 'true';
        namesDiv.contenteditable = 'true';
        namesDiv.className = "crewNames";
        namesDiv.ondragstart = function(){dragStart(event)
            if(event.target.type=="range")event.preventDefault();
            event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
            console.log("Dragging...");
        };
        namesDiv.onclick = function(){alert("ytry");};
        namesDiv.innerHTML = arrInbound[i][3][S];
        tagElRight.appendChild(namesDiv)        
    }
```

Comment: `event` _is_ undefined. You never create it. Or there is code missing.

Comment: How do I create it? excuse my ignorance, I'm still new to this.

Comment: I don't know. It is usually passed into an event handling function, so normally, you just take it and use it and that's it. You can also create events programmatically but I doubt that's what you want to do.